# position fixed not working inside Owl carousel (fixed position prev next button on carousel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I need to make fixed position of `<div class="btn">` on vertically middle of the screen (especially on small device). Unfortunately, some classes inside owl carousel prevent this manual positioning.

I have tried to append the div element to body with jQuery:

```
jQuery('.btn').appendTo("body");
```

It works, but conflicted with other buttons (showing all buttons at first page).

How can I solve this issue?

Code:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  loop: false,
  nav: false,
  dots: false,
  center: true,
  mouseDrag: false,
  touchDrag: false,
  autoHeight: true,
  margin: 10,
  smartSpeed: 500,
  URLhashListener: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash'
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 2000px;
}

.one {
  background: #bec4bd;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: #41253c;
}

.linkA {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.linkB {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="page one" data-hash="page1">
    Please see the button position!
    <div class="btn">
    <a href="#page2" class="linkB">Page 2</a>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="page two" data-hash="page2">
    Please see the button position!
    <div class="btn">
    <a href="#page1" class="linkA">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="page three" data-hash="page3" style="color:#fff;">
    Please see the button position!
    <div class="btn">
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/b01thk75/)

Comment: Can you be more specify where you want the button to be? at present I see it is in the bottom right, so you need it in the bottom center?

Comment: Buttons should be `position: fixed` (no need to scroll with page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inside `scroll` of carousel and `position` `sticky` would solve your problem

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  loop: false,
  nav: false,
  dots: false,
  center: true,
  mouseDrag: false,
  touchDrag: false,
  autoHeight: true,
  margin: 0,
  smartSpeed: 500,
  URLhashListener: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash'
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
}
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 2000px;
}

.one {
  background: #bec4bd;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: #41253c;
}

.linkA {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.linkB {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.btn {
 position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="page one" data-hash="page1">
    Please see the button position!
    <div class="btn">
    <a href="#page2" class="linkB">Page 2</a>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="page two" data-hash="page2">
    Please see the button position!
    <div class="btn">
    <a href="#page1" class="linkA">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="page three" data-hash="page3" style="color:#fff;">
    Please see the button position!
    <div class="btn">
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```